# null value passed from angularjs frontend to jersey backend

Tags: angularjs, jersey

i am using angular front end and java jersey as back end .when i submit data from the form ,null values are passed instead of the actual form data. This is my form

```html
<div id="main">
<h1>Create Leave</h1>
<form class="form-horizontal" >
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="employeeName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Employee Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <input type="text" id="num" class="form-control" ng-model="num" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="leaveType" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Leave Type</label>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
         <select id="leaveType" class="form-control" ng-model="leaveType">
            <option value="hospital">Hospital</option>
            <option value="l1">leave type 2</option>
            <option value="l2">leave type 3</option>
            <option value="l3">leave type 4</option>
            <option value="l4">leave type 5</option>
            <option value="l5">leave type 6</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-7"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="leaveStartDate" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Leave Start Date</label>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
         <input type="date" id="startDate" class="form-control" ng-model="startDate" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-7"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="leaveEndDate" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Leave End Date</label>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
         <input type="date" id="endDate" class="form-control" ng-model="endDate" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-7"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
         <span><b>Is Half Day leave</b></span>
         <div class="radio">
            <label><input value="Yes" type="radio" name="halfDay" ng-model="isHalfDay" />Yes</label>
         </div>
         <div class="radio">
            <label><input value="No" type="radio" name="halfDay" ng-model="isHalfDay" />No</label>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <button ng-click="add()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> 
   <button ng-click="resetForm()" class="btn">Reset</button>
</form>
```

and this is the controller

```html
app.controller("MyAddController", function($scope, $http) {
 //$scope.test = {};
    $scope.add = function() {
    // console.log("------------>"+JSON.stringify($scope.test));
        $http.post("webapi/blog/create", {
            params: {
                signum: $scope.num,
                leaveType: $scope.leaveType,
                startDate: $scope.startDate,
                endDate: $scope.endDate,
                isHalfDay: $scope.isHalfDay

            }
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            if (data) {
                $scope.data = data;
                alert("success");
            }
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("error");
        })
    }
});
```

and the jersey code

```html
 @POST
 @Path("create")
 @Produces({ "application/json" })
 public String create(@BeanParam LeaveDetails ld) {
  System.out.println("Entered here");
  System.out.println(ld.getIsHalfDay());
  System.out.println(ld.getNum());
  System.out.println(ld.getEndDate());
  System.out.println(ld.getStartdate());
  System.out.println(ld.getLeaveType());
  new AddLeaveDao().addDetails(ld);
  System.out.println("Returned  here");
  return "{}";
 }
```

Please help

Comment: Are you getting all parameters inside $scope.add function?

Comment: yes..i am getting the values .i checked it by adding console.log inside add function

Comment: Then, it is your backend code issue. You can check it in Network tab in Chrome browser. Whether the API is called or not and the data is posted or not.

Comment: yeah ...thats what i am not understanding whats wrong with the backend code.Thats why i have attached the backend jersey code as well